# How to run my Java application with one click from IE11?

Tags: java, internet-explorer-11

I would like to run my Java application (on a new window is OK) by clicking on a link on an HTML page opened with IE11. Is this a complicated process? This needs to happen on my personal PC and not to users accessing from outside. So only locally.

Comment: There are a great number of java application platforms including web applications, desktop GUI applications and command line application - of course if you had a web application then this of course could run *within* IE11 and other web browsers

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with JAVA. I developed my application in NetBeans (I didn't use JApplet) and now I'd like to open the application within an html page. How can I achieve this?